# Integrating doesn't work in some cases

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, fourier-analysis

I tried to calculate below integral but there was no response.

```
Integrate[Exp[-t  Abs[k]^a - I k x]/Abs[k]^a, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Could anyone find a way for calculating it analytically?

t is bigger than zero and a is between 0 and 2 and x is real.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the constants `t`, `a`, `x`?  For instance, are they real?

Comment: And did you mean `i` to be another constant or mybe the imginary unit `I`?

Comment: i is the the sign of imaginary  @corey979

Comment: @OliverRange What corey was implying is that in *Mathematica* the imaginary unit is represented by UPPERCASE `I`. The system is case-sensitive.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.  Also, this integral probably converges only for a small range of `a`.

Comment: t is bigger than zero and a is between 0 and 2. There is no condition on x. @bbgodfrey

Comment: I got the point and corrected the question. Thank you @MarcoB

Comment: I did edit it. @bbgodfrey

Answer (score 1):

**Error corrected** (pointed out by [user64494](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7152/user64494).)

`Integrate` typically has difficulty  with `Abs[]`.  However, the integral can be simplified by splitting the range of integration, eliminating the `Abs[]` in each, and then recombining the two pieces.

```
FullSimplify[Simplify[Exp[-t Abs[k]^a - I k x]/Abs[k]^a, k > 0 && 0 < a < 2] + 
    Simplify[Exp[-t Abs[k]^a - I k x]/Abs[k]^a /. k -> -k, k > 0 && 0 < a < 2]]
(* 2 E^(-k^a t) k^-a Cos[k x] *)
```

The integral then becomes

```
2 Integrate[Exp[-t k^a] Cos[k x]/k^a, {k, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> 1 > a > 0 && t > 0 && x ∈ Reals]
```

Note that the range of `a` is reduced to `1 > a > 0`, because the integral does not converge at `k == 0` for larger `a`.  Even with this change, `Integrate` claims that the integral does not converge,

> Integrate::idiv  Integral of E^(-k^a t) k^-a Cos[k x] does not converge on {0,∞}.

But it actually does converge, as can be seen from the simpler integral.

```
2 Integrate[Cos[k x]/k^a, {k, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> 1 > a > 0 && x ∈ Reals]
(* 2 Abs[x]^(-1 + a) Gamma[1 - a] Sin[(a π)/2] *)
```

Moreover, the integral can be performed explicitly for `a == 1/2`, and perhaps for other values.

```
2 Integrate[Exp[-t k^(1/2)] Cos[k x]/k^(1/2), {k, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> t > 0 && x ∈ Reals]

(* (Sqrt[2 π] (Cos[t^2/(4 x)] (1 - 2 FresnelS[t/(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[Abs[x]])]) 
    + (-1 + 2 FresnelC[t/(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[Abs[x]])]) Sin[t^2/(4 Abs[x])]))/Sqrt[Abs[x]] *)
```

Comment: there is another condition on x which may help. x is real. @bbgodfrey

Comment: @OliverRange  This additional constraint seems to help only for specific values of `a`.  Probably, `Integrate` is unable to obtain symbolic results for most values of `a`.  Perhaps, they do not even exist.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: The integral under consideration diverges for $a>1$.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: You are not right. The exponent is $a/2$, not $a$ as in the question, in your addendum. This is another cup of tea.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: The integral of $\left| k\right| ^{-a} e^{-t \left| k\right| ^a-i k x} $ diverges at $k=0$ if $a>1$.

Comment: @user64494  Thanks for your persistence.  I have corrected the error in my answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: If I were you, I also noticed your  two  comments deleted by you.